# Regular Expression, extract the number with a decimal place from API input

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to extract the number with 2 decimal places from my APIs input. These data are shown with text and comma but I only need the number with a decimal. I'm pretty sure this isn't the right way of using regex101. I'm a beginner in coding so I don't have much knowledge about a Regular Expression

1:     {"symbol":"BTCUSDT","price":"34592.99000000"}

Attempt to extract: 34592.99000000 using regex101 "\d+........"

2:     {"THB_BTC":{"id":1,"last":1102999.13,"lowestAsk":1102999.08,"highestBid":1100610.1,"percentChange":2.94,"baseVolume":202.54340749,"quoteVolume":221380256.57,"isFrozen":0,"high24hr":1108001,"low24hr":1061412.72,"change":31496.06,"prevClose":1102999.13,"prevOpen":1071503.07}}

Attempt to extract: 1102999.13 using regex101 "\d\d....."

These attempts only get me close but not 100% to the target, I believe there is a right way of doing this.

here's my code

```
import requests
import re


result = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT")
result1 = requests.get("https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker/?sym=THB_BTC&lmt=10")

result.text
result1.text

api0 = re.compile(r"\d+........").findall(result.text)[0]
api1 = re.compile(r"\d\d.....").findall(result1.text)[0]

print(result.text)
print(result1.text)
```

If you have any advice please do. I'm highly appreciated in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier and better way to do this, without regex

```py
import requests
import re


result = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT").json()
result1 = requests.get("https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker/?sym=THB_BTC&lmt=10").json()

data_1 = format(float(result['price']), '.2f')
data_2 = format(float(result1['THB_BTC']['last']), '.2f')

print(data_1, data_2)
```

```
34602.98 1101999.95
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that. Change your regex to `\d+\.\d+`

```
import requests
import re


result = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT")
result1 = requests.get("https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker/?sym=THB_BTC&lmt=10")

api0 = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+").findall(result.text)[0]
api1 = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+").findall(result1.text)[0]

print(result.text)
print(result1.text)

print(api0)
print(api1)
```